# Error: ER_NO_SUCH_TABLE: how to synchronize the missing table after updating DB

Tags: mysql, node.js, rest, api

i created a database having one table of Patient, i did my functions of get and post on rest api 
when i wanted to add a new table of Doctors i had this error mn my CMD

[image]

So any one has an idea about how to update the database with synchronization of those files
thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

1. Deleting existing migrations
2. Add migration
3. Update database

Comment: i don't have an existing migration how can i apply it

Comment: you can check the DbContext file for the new table Doctors. Then Add new migration . you can try update-database with -verbose option, so that you can see the list of sql statements applied on target database

Comment: am very new at node js could you suggest some tutorial please

Comment: https://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/code-based-migration-in-code-first.aspx